# UnsupportedOperationException on EdgeEffect

Tags: android, android-viewpager, typed-arrays

My app fails when initializing a ViewPager that is inflated from xml. The following is the line that crashes from the Android src EdgeCompat.java

```
final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(com.android.internal.R.styleable.EdgeEffect);
final int themeColor = a.getColor(com.android.internal.R.styleable.EdgeEffect_colorEdgeEffect, 0xff666666);
```

This is called by `ViewPager.initViewPager()` and all I can see in the stack trace is there is an error when inflating the layout.

I have attached the layout and stack trace below

Layout

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:overScrollMode="never" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

</merge>
```

Stacktrace

```
Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor (TypedArray.java:404)
    android.widget.EdgeEffect. (EdgeEffect.java:121)
    android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompatIcs.newEdgeEffect (EdgeEffectCompatIcs.java:30)
    android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat$EdgeEffectIcsImpl.newEdgeEffect (EdgeEffectCompat.java:92)
    android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat. (EdgeEffectCompat.java:133)
    android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.initViewPager (ViewPager.java:370)
    android.support.v4.view.ViewPager. (ViewPager.java:355)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:288)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:607)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:743)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:806)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:479)
    android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:414)
```

Comment: How does it fail? Can you show a stacktrace?

Comment: `"com.android.internal.R.styleable"` it is **NOT** a part of official SDK

Comment: @pskink that's what I found on the Android source

Comment: android source has access to itself, we don't, we have to use the interface provided by an SDK

Comment: @pskink yes, I'm not accessing the android source. I'm simply creating a ViewPager which makes this call

Comment: The problem is I don't have access to that. This breaks on the viewpager constructor, which I only inflate from xml

Comment: so whats the stacktrace?

Comment: @nicopico question updated with stacktrace

Comment: Can you share your layout XML as well ?

Comment: did you try to narrow it down? for example by using ViewPager with only two attrs: layout_* ?